# XML Attribute Update

Tags: .net, xml, powershell, attributes

I have an XML similar to this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Format_Version>1.0</Format_Version>
  <Reporting>
  </Reporting>
  <Jobs>
        <!--<Job>
                <Name>SpaceCheck</Name>
                <Job_Type>SpaceCheck</Job_Type>
                <Schedule>
                    <Start_Time>0300</Start_Time>
                    <Frequency>24 hours</Frequency>
                    <Max_Run_Time_In_Seconds>10</Max_Run_Time_In_Seconds>
                </Schedule>
                <Parameters>
                    <Drive>C</Drive>
                    <Drive>D</Drive>
                </Parameters>
        </Job>
        <Job>
                <Name>CPUCheck</Name>
                <Job_Type>UsageMonitor</Job_Type>
                <Schedule>
                    <Frequency>3 minutes</Frequency>
                </Schedule>
                <Parameters>
                    <Threshold>90%</Threshold>
                    <Duration>10 minutes</Duration>
                </Parameters>
        </Job>
        <Job>
                <Name>overloaded CPUCheck</Name>
                <Job_Type>CPUcheck2</Job_Type>
                <Schedule>
                    <Frequency>3 minutes</Frequency>
                </Schedule>
                <Parameters>
                    <Threshold>80%</Threshold>
                    <Duration>50 minutes</Duration>
                </Parameters>
            </Job>-->
        <Job>
          <Name>Connection</Name>
          <Job_Type>Connectivity</Job_Type>
          <Schedule>
            <Start_Time>1900</Start_Time>
            <Frequency>1</Frequency>
            <Maximum_Runtime>30</Maximum_Runtime>
          </Schedule>
          <Parameters>
            <ToErrInHours>1</ToErrInHours>
            <Days>1</Days>
            <Threshold>70</Threshold>
          </Parameters>
        </Job>
      </Jobs>
    </Configuration>
```

I am trying to update the value of Start_Time from 1900 to 2300. The problem is the element getting updated but not the value. How can I resolve this.

tried to update - this way :

```
#Get the content of the Config File
$xdoc = [xml](Get-content "C:\Program Files (x86)\Alpha\Beta\gamma.xml")
#Get the value of the Attribute key
$StartTime = $XDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Start_Time[1]")
echo $StartTime
# Set the attribute
$StartTime.SetAttribute("Start_Time", "2300")
$xdoc.Save('C:\Program Files (x86)\Alpha\Beta\gamma.xml')
echo $StartTime
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change 1900 to 2300 by calling `SetAttribute()`, however, 1900 is not an attribute of the element. You should set the `InnerText` instead, like this:

```
$StartTime.InnerText = "2300"
```

[Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx#Load) an example from MSDN. It uses the following as the sample XML. Notice how `<title>` and `<price>` are like the `<Start_Time>` element you want to change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books xmlns="http://www.contoso.com/books">
  <book genre="novel" ISBN="1-861001-57-8" publicationdate="1823-01-28">
    <title>Pride And Prejudice</title>
    <price>24.95</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel" ISBN="1-861002-30-1" publicationdate="1985-01-01">
    <title>The Handmaid's Tale</title>
    <price>29.95</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel" ISBN="1-861001-45-3" publicationdate="1811-01-01">
    <title>Sense and Sensibility</title>
    <price>19.95</price>
  </book>
</books>
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx#Edit) is the code they use to update various parts of the XML. They use `InnerText` to change the values for `<title>` and `<price>`.

```
public void editBook(string title, string ISBN, string publicationDate,
    string genre, string price, XmlNode book, bool validateNode, bool generateSchema)
{

    XmlElement bookElement = (XmlElement)book;

    // Get the attributes of a book.        
    bookElement.SetAttribute("ISBN", ISBN);
    bookElement.SetAttribute("genre", genre);
    bookElement.SetAttribute("publicationdate", publicationDate);

    // Get the values of child elements of a book.
    bookElement["title"].InnerText = title;
    bookElement["price"].InnerText = price;

    if (validateNode)
    {
        validateXML(generateSchema, bookElement.OwnerDocument);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fix - that exactly worked and my XML doc is updated. sorry for the mistake - accidentally clicked the down arrow - that is completely inadvertent.